# Fetch & show item details

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently learning Flutter and developing a Shopping List.
In the backend, there's a Laravel instance providing the following Endpoints:

- /lists -> A list of all shopping lists
- /lists/{listId}/items -> All items in the list

For the Flutter side, I've created a provider which fetches all lists from the server.

```
Future<void> init() async {
  this.lists = await this.service.getLists();
  notifyListeners();
}
```

This data (`<List<ListModel>>`) is retreived by my widget and displayed through ListView.builder. The RefreshIndicator just refreshes the provider data by run the init method again.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final provider = Provider.of<ShoppingListProvider>(context);
  List<ListModel> lists = provider.lists;

...
child: RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: () => provider.init(),
```

Now, if I click on the ListTile, I'd like to display all items. They should be fetched from the API as well, and I'd like to refresh the item list too. Unfortunately, I don't manage to get this data provided through the provider, as it requires the "listId".

Maybe someone can give me a hint on this?

Fetched from inside the widget, which works, but then I can't refresh the data. It somehow should be provided through the provider

Comment: I don’t believe you should declare a final variable inside a widget’s build method. This will result in an insane amount of re-initialisations everytime the UI gets rebuilt, which is not what I think you desire. As for your problem, maybe try adding a listener which listens to the value of your provider, then on it updating (calling `notifyListeners` it calls `setState` to rebuild the UI?

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I'll re check regarding the variable. The problem is, I'm not sure how to fetch my shoppinglist items with the provider, as I can't just fetch all of them and store them in the same variable (like I do for lists). I can only fetch one at a time by providing the parent list ID. Yes I could do this in my provider, but if I open another list, there's still data from the last-opened list until it gets updated again.

Comment: can you provide more code. quite difficult to debug with just the code you are currently providing